# A regex to find a country name

Tags: php, regex

I need a regex to find country name in news :
The name can be at the start or at the end of the line.
It can start with an uppercase or not.
It can contain - (I have problem with Etat-Unis (United-State).
I tried :

```
'/\b'.$name.'\B/i'
```

But it didn't work with name at the start of the line or at the end.
I tried :

```
'/(\b|^)'.$name.'(\B|$)/i'
```

I think this regex is good but it find 'Etat-Unis' and not 'Népal', 'Etat-Unis' is before 'Népal' in my array, I think the problem is the `-`
Thanks you for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `'/\b'.$name.'\b/i'`

Notice the lowercase `\b` at the end. `\B` is a non word boundary and not what you want. Start/End of line is not a problem, there is also a word boundary.